# jQuery datepicker opens on the wrong date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have following date format `31.12.2049` which is December 31st, 2049.  When I click on the icon to open the datepicker, today's date is selected.  This is using `Norwegian Bokmal (nb-NO)` and I noticed the date is formatted in the text, but when I open the calendar, I don't see any norwegian translations.

The date shown in the input is `31.12.2049`, so I except the ShortDateFormat to be `dd.mm.yyyy`, but this does not work when I do:

```
$(input).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'});
```

I have to do this instead:

```
$(input).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
```

The problem is that when I inspect the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` property, it shows the format as `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: The datepicker interprets `yy` as a four-digit year, so `dd.mm.yyyy` will be `31.12.20492049`. Could you provide more details? There's not nearly enough information in the post to give a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set dateFormat ?

Like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
});
```

Default date format is mm/dd/yy

Comment: I didn't set that because I could have multiple formats besides that, is there a way I can set the format based on the browsers culture?  It works fine for UK and French where the month and day are reversed from US and I didn't have to set the format.

Comment: I'im confused on something.  The date shown in the input  is `31.12.2049`, but the format I should use is `dd.mm.yy`, I would except it to be `dd.mm.yyyy`, but that fails in this case.  When I inspect the ShortDateFormat, shows it as `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: I ended up having to convert .NET format to the jQuery format, but your answer is technically correct.